# How to make Fast Response Receive data from socket in android[Close]

Tags: android, sockets

i need help i have a problem in sending data using TCP server. I can send it via client to the server. but the data sent via the client to the server cannot be received quickly. we must first shut down the sender's socket connection and the data can be received. can someone help me for this problem i try much tutorial from google searching still same. thank you very much

code:

```
class TCPServer extends AsyncTask<String,String,String> {
    public String message;
    private DataInputStream stream;
    private ServerSocket socket;
    private PrintWriter writer;
    private OutputStream outputStream;
    private BufferedReader reader;

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
        try {
           socket=new ServerSocket(4000);
           Socket socket1=socket.accept();
            this.reader=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket1.getInputStream()));
            this.outputStream=socket1.getOutputStream();
            this.writer=new PrintWriter(outputStream,true);
            writer.write("Hellow this is from server to client");
            writer.flush();
            while(true){
                this.message=reader.readLine();
                Log.i("information message",message);
            }
        } catch(UnknownHostException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e("error in here",e.toString());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e("error in here",e.toString());
        }
        return message;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Wait A minute",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),s.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
       Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),values[0],Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}
```

[image]

DONE !! thanks for anyone help i am just use socket and server socket for receive i just use thread and can transfer it to other device thank you

Comment: why to use the low level sockets? do you have huge amount of data to be sent? or just several small messages?

Comment: @pskink i want to send file message to server which can send file data to server but now i want to try for simple send data but cannot receive data can you help me please.

Comment: file message? what you mean? is it a file? is it huge? why dont you simply use [okhttp](http://square.github.io/okhttp/)?

Comment: @pskink yes sir i want to sent file from client like 192.168.1.102 to 192.168.1.106 which connected to same wifi , i can do that but for receive data i need to stop connected socket sir, ok thank you sir i will try okhttp

Comment: https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/Recipes#posting-a-file

Comment: `we must first shut down the sender's socket connection` ??? How would you be able to send data if there is no connection? Your question does not make sense.

Comment: Your server is trying to read lines from client. Now does the client send lines?

Comment: The server sends as welcome a string. Not a line. What is the client trying to read in first action?

Comment: `why dont you simply use okhttp?` – @pskink ??? Simply? He would have to install a webserver on his Android device first.

Comment: @greenapps the client is on android device, not server

Comment: ??? This TcpServer AsyncTask looks for Android. What makes you think its not? And it does not handle http protocol.

Comment: @greenapps you are right - it seems that client and server are both on android - even though - the [server](https://github.com/gseguin/NanoHTTPd/blob/master/src/NanoHTTPd.java) is not a monster if it has less then 1000 lines of code including lots of comments

Comment: @greenapps I want to make my Android can connect with other Androids using TCP server. but I have successfully sent via the client to the server but the data received by the server does not enter directly. part of the client needs to disconnect first before the data can appear on the server section. I have tried repeatedly to stay the same. can you help me please i try library from okhttp still doesn't work

Comment: You only repeated yourself. You already told that. But you did not react on the things i said/asked trying to help you.

Comment: Read again what @greenapps commented above, and try to understand what a 'line' is.  It's not just an array of chars - it has a structure.